# Python Quick Sort swapping values once but then duplicating values

Tags: python-3.x, quicksort

I am trying to write a quicksort in python, and, whilst I have managed to get it to swap values, after one pass through the function, it replaces the last swapped value with the first. So, for example, if it were to swap a 5 and a 1, then it would swap it to make 1,5 and then, after 1 pass, it will change to 1,1.

```
a = [5,2,3,4,1]
b = [5,2,3,4,1]
l_point = 0; r_point = len(a)-1

print(a)

while l_point != r_point and l_point >= 0 and r_point >= 0:

    while a[l_point] <= a[r_point] and l_point != r_point and l_point >= 0 and r_point >= 0:
        l_point += 1

    del(a[l_point])
    a.insert(l_point, b[r_point])
    del(a[r_point])
    a.insert(r_point, b[l_point])
    print(a)

    while a[l_point] > a[r_point] and l_point != r_point and l_point >= 0 and r_point >= 0:
        r_point -= 1

    del(a[l_point])
    a.insert(l_point, b[r_point])
    del(a[r_point])
    a.insert(r_point, b[l_point])
    print(a)

print(a)
```

Output:

```
[5, 2, 3, 4, 1]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1]
```

Any insight appreciated!

Comment: be careful with indexes: if they accidentally reach `-1` no error is issued, it just picks the latest element.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks for the tip. Checked whether that was the issue and it isn't. I have added a catch to fix that issue though, which will be added to the post shortly